# CurrentUtcDateTime does not exist - Entity Framework and MySql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I am having a problem with canonical functions in Entity Framework 4.1 and MySql Connector/Net 6.4.3.
According to Microsoft cannonical functions are understood and translated into the local SQL dialect by all database providers from the SQL generated by LINQ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626.aspx However, my code chokes on CurrentUtcDateTime(), which is listed here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx

Here is the LINQ query (from NopCommerce) that generates the offensive SQL:

```cs
    public List<Poll> GetPolls(int languageId, int pollCount, bool loadShownOnHomePageOnly)
    {
        bool showHidden = NopContext.Current.IsAdmin;


        var query = (IQueryable<Poll>)_context.Polls;
        if (!showHidden)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.Published);
            query = query.Where(p => !p.StartDate.HasValue || p.StartDate <= DateTime.UtcNow);
            query = query.Where(p => !p.EndDate.HasValue || p.EndDate >= DateTime.UtcNow);
        }
        if (loadShownOnHomePageOnly)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.ShowOnHomePage);
        }
        if (languageId > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(p => p.LanguageId == languageId);
        }

        query = query.OrderBy(p => p.DisplayOrder);
        if (pollCount > 0)
        {
            query = query.Take(pollCount);
        }

        var polls = query.ToList();

        return polls;
    }
```

query.ToList() generates the SQL below:

```sql
SELECT`Project1`.`PollID`, `Project1`.`LanguageID`, `Project1`.`Name`, 
`Project1`.`Published`, `Project1`.`ShowOnHomePage`, `Project1`.`DisplayOrder`, 
`Project1`.`SystemKeyword`, `Project1`.`StartDate`, `Project1`.`EndDate`
FROM (SELECT`Extent1`.`PollID`, `Extent1`.`LanguageID`, `Extent1`.`Name`, 
`Extent1`.`SystemKeyword`, `Extent1`.`Published`, `Extent1`.`ShowOnHomePage`, 
`Extent1`.`DisplayOrder`, `Extent1`.`StartDate`, `Extent1`.`EndDate`
FROM `Nop_Poll` AS `Extent1` WHERE ((((`Extent1`.`Published` = 1) AND 
((`Extent1`.`StartDate` IS  NULL) OR (`Extent1`.`StartDate` <= (CurrentUtcDateTime())))) 
AND ((`Extent1`.`EndDate` IS  NULL) OR (`Extent1`.`EndDate` >= (CurrentUtcDateTime())))) 
AND (`Extent1`.`ShowOnHomePage` = 1)) AND (`Extent1`.`LanguageID` = @p__linq__0)) 
AS `Project1` ORDER BY `Project1`.`DisplayOrder` ASC LIMIT 2147483647
```

This is error is outputed:

```
*FUNCTION myDatabase.CurrentUtcDateTime does not exist 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: FUNCTION myDatabase.CurrentUtcDateTime does not exist*
```

Am I missing something? Please advice. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered this exact same problem and lost almost two days trying to figure it out. It appears to be a bug in the EntityFramework mappings for MySql.

The solution is to move the **DateTime.UtcNow** calculation outside of the scoped lambda and plug in the actual value.

```
var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
query = query.Where(p => p.Published);
query = query.Where(p => !p.StartDate.HasValue || p.StartDate <= utcNow);
query = query.Where(p => !p.EndDate.HasValue || p.EndDate >= utcNow);
```

Comment: I consider myself lucky to have stumbled onto your answer so quickly. Insane that this bug still hasn't been fixed after 4 years.

Comment: Just ran into this as well; ridiculous. I guess no one is listening to the bug reports.  Just add this to the "IsPrimaryKey" errors for the entity designer as well, still around for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Bohemian's suggestion, I fixed this issue with a "bypass" function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `your_schema`.`CurrentUtcDateTime` ()
RETURNS TIMESTAMP DETERMINISTIC
RETURN UTC_TIMESTAMP();
```

Comment: I don't think this is replication safe.  If I had two database and executed this function on one, then later it replicated to the other, it would produce separate results. I think 'DETERMINISTIC' shouldn't be used here.

Comment: not a good solution, hassle to keep adding this function to new environment servers.

Answer (score -1):

Use [UTC_TIMESTAMP()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The SQL is generated automatically by EF, so I cannot change the function, or is there a switch to do this (this is my first EF project, so I'm still learning).