# SqlQuerry ToList() works but Linq(Iqueryable) does not?

Tags: c#, linq

I have weired problem, and don't get it at all. So I have this SqlQuerry

```
var blogs = context.Meal.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Meal WHERE PersonID=" + id.ToString() + "AND DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),Datetime) <= 7 ").ToList();
```

And that works perfectly, but I tried to transfer that expression to linq, and i can't get ToList() to work

```
var blogs1 = from c in context.Meal
            where c.PersonID.Equals(id)
            where (DateTime.Now.Date - c.Datetime).Days <= 7
            select c;
List<Meal> blogs = blogs1.ToList();
```

I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with
>   comparable types.

I googled a lot, tried first with var blogs, then tried with `ToList<Meal>` tried `DateTime.Now` but i copied expression from net and then because of Deferred Execution I wrote this

```
var blogs = (from c in context.Meal
            where c.PersonID.Equals(id)
            where (DateTime.Now.Date - c.Datetime).Days <= 7
            select c).ToList();
```

But no, it won't work :/
I am using System.Linq, and I read here on StackOverflow that Linq supports Iqueryable ToList.
Is it possible that my Linq is wrong it looks simple and i got it from net so it shouldn't be wrong?

If you need any more info type in comments I will add it. Thanks!

EDIT1: Changed .TotalDays to .Days as @garethb suggested, but error persists. 
EDIT2: I have tried this as Matias suggested

```
var now = DateTime.Now.Date;
var blogs1 = from c in context.Meal
             where c.PersonID.Equals(id)
             where EntityFunctions.DiffDays(now, c.Datetime) <= 7
             select c;
List<Meal> blogs = blogs1.ToList();
```

And got this error: (same with SqlFunctions)

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] DiffDays(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

For the finish I accidentally marked this question as duplicate but it isn't. I didn't get where is the problem, but main problem is in that Microsoft changed namespace of DiffDays method from EntityFunctions to DbContext in EF 6.x and that is why my Linq didn't work. In this example it maybe is comparison of dates, but it is on different way, so it is not duplicate.

Comment: Does Meal.Datetime allow null values?  I think you have some.  Also, what is the definition for "now" ?

Comment: @WesleyLong No it doesn't it is auto generated by adding any meal, no user input.There definition for now is added.
But I solved the problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: or just compare with 2 dates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21000287/date-difference-logic-in-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely using EntityFramework 6+. Which means you need to use the DbFunctions class. I have a few checkins I want to do to EF mainline to fix this problem, but for now use this code.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffdays(v=vs.113).aspx

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
var blogs1 = from c in context.Meal
             where c.PersonID.Equals(id)
             where DbFunctions.DiffDays(today, c.Datetime) <= 7
             select c;
List<Meal> blogs = blogs1.ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, this is it! it works now, it does count all data currently but I will bypass that minor bug, but Linq works finaly, thank you a lot Aron!

Answer (score 1):

```
// add to top of file
using System.Data.Entity;

// code
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
var blogs1 = from c in context.Meal
            where c.PersonID == id
            && DbFunctions.DiffDays(today, c.Datetime) <= 7
            select c;
List<Meal> blogs = blogs1.ToList();
```

See [DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx), these are c# expressions that translate into sql server functions.

Comment: Tried that to before EntityFunctions, same problem

Comment: @Vulisha - are you sure its not the `c.PersonID.Equals(id)` ? This should be `c.PersonID == id`. Primitive types are not treated as objects in EF expressions when they are converted to sql statements.

Comment: oh i didn't see that, sec I will try it now!

Comment: @Vulisha - That in combination with the date comparison should fix it. Also you can pic either `EntityFunctions` or `SqlFunctions`, both work on Sql Server but should you ever change the db provider then the former would be better.

Comment: again same error as in edit2

Comment: @Vulisha - sorry, I have updated my answer. SqlFunctions and EntityFunctions are considered obsolete, use DbFunctions instead.

Comment: Nono, i removed that in this try, you can see whole code here https://github.com/Vulisha/CalorieCounter

Comment: yes yes, I really don't know why they do that stuff... makes developing very very hard. And one more sad news is it still doesn't work, it looks like             `DbFunctions.DiffDays(today, c.Datetime) <= 7` does not support `<=` operator it just gets all items